# TFS 2012 Configure Features Error - Unable to configure Planning Tools

Tags: tfs

When trying to "Configure Features" after upgrading to TFS 2012 to enable Code Review, My Work, Feedback, Planning Tools, and Storyboarding we're getting the following error:

[Error] TF400654: Unable to configure Planning Tools. The following element contains an error: BugWorkItems/BugWorkItems. TF400507: Each work item type must support an initial state value that matches one of the states defined in: BugWorkItems. The following work item types have initial states that do not include any states defined in the bug state configuration: Bug.

We are using the Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum 2.2 process template with some modifications.  From what I can tell they are mostly minor. If you'd like to look at the Process Template I'm more than happy to provide it.

When I get this error it suggests the closest match to our process template is "MSF for Agile Software Development 6.0". Would we lose all out modifications by switching to this process template?

Comment: What changes have you made to the Bug work item around states and transitions? What happens if you back those changes out?

Comment: @JohnSaunders, I uploaded the default Bug work item using witadmin importwitd then tried to Configure Features. This failed again with the same error. One thing I did notice was that if I open the bug work item type using the Process Editor Power Tool from the server it's still the old modified bug work item type. It seems like my changes to the Process Template aren't getting updated/refreshed.

Comment: What is you Initial Bug State for your Team Project? What is the name of your User Story type (PBI, Requirement, User Story)?

Comment: Andre editing the Process Template has no effect on existing projects, so you would have to import the WIT to the specific project. What is the first state of Bug in the specific project? I think it expects to be "To Do" but might be something else like "New".

Comment: @DaveShaw, the initial state for the Bug work item is Proposed. We use User Story for our User Story type.

Comment: @MikeR, that's strange as most of the documentation I've read online says to use the Process Editor Power Tool or witadmin command line tool to make these types of changes.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

- [Rename](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd312129.aspx) your User Story to "Product Backlog Item".
- Set the Initial State of you "Bug" to "Active".
- Try the Upgrade
- Rename your User Story Type back to "User Story".
- Remove the "Active" Initial State.
- Export your [Common Process Config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh500413.aspx) and add in your "Proposed" State into the Bug Configuration (see below).
- Import your Common Process Config.

Example **BugWorkItems**

```
<BugWorkItems category="Microsoft.BugCategory">
    <States>
      <State type="Proposed" value="Proposed" />
      <!-- more -->
    </States>
</BugWorkItems>
```

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem myself and resolved it.

Need to edit 'ProcessConfiguration.xml' file and remove the statuses that are not needed and add the statuses that are required refering the Bug.xml work item type.