# TFS Board Configuration Issue

Tags: tfs, kanban

I am trying to configure the TFS board for a new team project and I was able to create the work items, states, fields, etc. However, I am getting this when trying to Configure the TFS features.

Here are my questions:

1. Where can I find the "TypeFields/TypeField[type='ApplicationType'"?
2. Should I go ahead and destroy the work items and run feature enablement to get rid of TF400612?

Error/Warning Log:

`[Warning] TF400612: The existing work item type 'Code Review Request' is reused. If the feature 'Code Review' is not behaving correctly, you can destroy the existing work item type and rerun feature enablement.`

`[Warning] TF400612: The existing work item type 'Code Review Response' is reused. If the feature 'Code Review' is not behaving correctly, you can destroy the existing work item type and rerun feature enablement.`

`[Warning] TF400612: The existing work item type 'Feedback Request' is reused. If the feature 'Feedback' is not behaving correctly, you can destroy the existing work item type and rerun feature enablement.`

`[Warning] TF400612: The existing work item type 'Feedback Response' is reused. If the feature 'Feedback' is not behaving correctly, you can destroy the existing work item type and rerun feature enablement.`

`[Error] TF400654: Unable to configure Planning Tools. The following element contains an error: TypeFields/TypeField[type='ApplicationStartInformation']. TF400330: The application start information field for feedback request is not configured correctly. Contact your Team Foundation Server administrator to correct the configuration.`

`[Error] TF400654: Unable to configure Planning Tools. The following element contains an error: TypeFields/TypeField[type='ApplicationLaunchInstructions']. TF400329: The application launch instructions field for feedback request is not configured correctly. Contact your Team Foundation Server administrator to correct the configuration.`

`[Error] TF400654: Unable to configure Planning Tools. The following element contains an error: TypeFields/TypeField[type='ApplicationType']. TF400328: The application types for feedback request are not configured correctly. Contact your Team Foundation Server administrator to correct the configuration.`

`[Error] TF400654: Unable to configure Planning Tools. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: The TF400654 error is described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh913787.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16988559/tfs-2012-configure-features-error-unable-to-configure-planning-tools

Answer (score 0):

These fields are found in the ProcessTemplate.xml file.  It looks like yours is jacked up, so I'd go in and take a look.  It's in your process template under the "WorkItem Tracking"->"Process" folder.  Here is a [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh500408.aspx).  Also, your xml should look like the below for the Feedback work items:

```
<FeedbackRequestWorkItems category="Microsoft.FeedbackRequestCategory" pluralName="Feedback Requests" singularName="Feedback Request">    
  <States>
          <State value="Active" type="InProgress" />
          <State value="Closed" type="Complete" />    
  </States> 
</FeedbackRequestWorkItems> 
<FeedbackResponseWorkItems category="Microsoft.FeedbackResponseCategory" pluralName="Feedback Responses" singularName="Feedback Response">    
  <States>    
    <State value="Active" type="InProgress" />    
    <State value="Closed" type="Complete" />    
  </States> 
</FeedbackResponseWorkItems>
```